# Sorting ListView error

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

```
private void contactsListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ItemComparer(e.Column); //error
    listView1.Sort();
}

class ItemComparer : IComparer<ListViewItem>
{
    private int col;
    public ItemComparer()
    {
        col = 0;
    }
    public ItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(ListViewItem x, ListViewItem y)
    {
        int returnVal = -1;
        returnVal = String.Compare(x.SubItems[col].Text, y.SubItems[col].Text);
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Moj_Program.itemComparer' to 'System.Collections.IComparer'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong?
In case someone needs the whole code here it is:

```
public partial class WereToSell : Form
{
    Update UpdateStations = new Update();

    public WereToSell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void contactsListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ItemComparer(e.Column);
        listView1.Sort();
    }
    int[] RegionIDs = { 10000054,10000069,10000001,10000036,10000043,10000064,10000037,
                      10000067,10000067,10000030,10000052,10000049,10000065,10000016,
                      10000042,10000028,10000048,10000032,10000044,10000020,10000020,
                      10000038,10000033,10000002,10000068};
    string[] RegionNames = { "Aridia","Black Rise","Derelik","Devoid","Domain","Essence","Everyshore","Genesis","Heimatar","Kador","Khanid"
    ,"Kor-Azor","Lonetrek","Metropolis","Molden Heath","Placid","Sinq Laison","Solitude","Tash-Murkon","The Bleak Lands"
    ,"The Citadel","The Forge","Verge Vendor"};
    public static int ItemNumber;
    public static string ItemName;
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string RegionName = comboBox1.Text;
        string Ammount = AmmountTextBox.Text;

        int ArrayLenght = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < RegionNames.Length; i++)
        {
            if (RegionNames[i] == RegionName)
            {
                ArrayLenght = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        var List = UpdateStations.FindStations(RegionIDs[ArrayLenght], ItemListView.ItemNumber, Convert.ToInt32(Ammount));
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Key.Length; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem itemlist = new ListViewItem();
            itemlist.Text = List.Value[i];
            itemlist.SubItems.Add(List.Key[i].ToString());
            itemlist.SubItems.Add(RegionIDs[ArrayLenght].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(itemlist);

        }
    }

}
class ItemComparer : Comparer<ListViewItem>
{
    private int col;
    public ItemComparer()
    {
        col = 0;
    }
    public ItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(ListViewItem x, ListViewItem y)
    {
        int returnVal = -1;
        returnVal = String.Compare(x.SubItems[col].Text, y.SubItems[col].Text);
        return returnVal;
    }


}
```

I have another question tho. What if I placed that in a void methode instead of button click and just execute it when i want? How a methode like that should look?

Comment: Maybe, you should infer non-generic `IComparer` instead of `IComparer<T>`

Comment: Tryed.That didint work.New nerror at class ItemComparer : Comparer<ListViewItem> . ItemComparer does not implement inherited abstract member

Comment: `I have another question tho.` You must post it as new question.

Answer (score 1):

Derive from `Comparer<T>` instead of implementing `IComparer<T>`

```
class ItemComparer : Comparer<ListViewItem>
{
    ....
}
```

The `Comparer<T>` already has had implemented the non-generic interface `IComparer` which is suitable in your case.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is MS suggestion:

> We recommend that you derive from the Comparer<T> class instead of
>   implementing the IComparer<T> interface, because the Comparer<T> class
>   provides an explicit interface implementation of the IComparer.Compare
>   method and the Default property that gets the default comparer for the
>   object.

Comment: That didint work.New nerror at class ItemComparer : Comparer<ListViewItem> . ItemComparer does not implement inherited abstract member

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You must implement the abstract method `public abstract int Compare(T x,T y)`.

Comment: @user3715205, As I mentioned, you must `override` the inherited abstract method `public abstract int Compare(T x,T y)`. You haven't done this, as I see in your updated post.